# c++ : Class pointer function prototype MATCHES class pointer function declaration, doesn't see private variable?

Tags: pointers, nodes, private

I am still new enough to C++, as some things still trip me. I often try to figure things out before asking questions, but this time, I'm stumped. I tried looking for answers to this problem, but I'm still not sure what exactly to call it, as I don't recall encountering it before, and no one described it to me. It looks like a "pointer function" to me, so that's all I can think to call it.

I intend to separate the following code into a .hpp, .cpp, and .main.

The reason I can't is because the function prototype by the arrow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct data
{
   string bookTitle;
   string bookAuthor;
   int month;
   int day;
   int year;
};

class Node
{
   data d;
   Node *link;
 public: 
   Node();
   Node(string title, string author, int mo, int da, int yr);

   void setLink(Node *ptr);
   Node *getLink(); <----------------------------

   string getTitle();
   string getAuthor();

   bool compareData (string title);
   void processData();
};
```

Is at odds with its declaration:

```
void Node::setLink(Node *ptr)
    {
        link = ptr;
    }

Node Node::*getLink() <----------------------------
    {
       return link;
    }
```

I get these back for the function Node Node::*getLink():

*error: 'link' was not declared in this scope
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*

HOWEVER, the program works just fine *when the function is declared within the class*. I can only guess that my syntax is not exactly right so as to gain access to the private link member of Node.

Again, I don't recall ever dealing with a situation like this and I don't even know what this kind of case is called.

I'm sorry I can't offer any further details immediately, as I have to be somewhere by 1:30. I will try to get back to anyone as soon as I can later today. If need be, here is the rest of my code:

cpp.sh/6lgc

Thank you so much for any help. If anyone can tell me what kind of case this is, please enlighten me!

Cheers,

-Jon

Comment: You did a simple typo: It must be `Node* Node::getLink() { ... }` in the implementation. Otherwise, the signature doesn't match and the compiler probably does not recognize this as the above declared method.

Comment: Remember, `T* t` and `T *t` declare the same thing, a pointer to `T` named `t`.  Similarly, `Node *getLink()` and `Node* getLink()` declare the same thing.  From this, what is the return type of `getLink()`?

Comment: Scheff: Thank you so much, that was it! :) I was wondering if I had simply misplaced the *. I won't be forgetting this!

Justin Time: the return type ought to be Node, I believe? I'm pretty sure that's what I have here, am I wrong?